# Все числа, содержащиеся в обоих файлах одновременно, удалить из первого

Tags: c++, файлы

Имеется такая учебная задача:

Создать два текстовых файла, все числа, содержащиеся в обоих файлах одновременно, удалить из первого файла. Дополнительных массивов и файлов не использовать.

Создаю файлы я вот так:

```
ofstream fout("1.txt");
fout << "619";
fout.close();
system("pause");

ofstream fout1("2.txt");
fout1 << "618";
fout1.close();
system("pause");
```

Далее требуется сравнить данные и удалить. Как это реализовать?

Comment: Также для удобства можно делать текстовый файл любого формата, например сделать одно числа, а можно отделить каждую цифру пробелом.

Comment: Открыть оба файла, считать в контейнеры `set` (или, скажем, `vector` и отсортировать), воспользоваться алгоритмом `set_difference`...

Comment: @Harry А не могли-бы с кодом ещё помочь?

Comment: @Harry Я считал строки в массив set. 
_ifstream f2("21.txt");

 getline(f2, s);
 ss << s;
 while (ss) {
  ss >> value;
  temp2.insert(value);
 }_
Теперь их нужно отсортировать? Как сортировать и для чего?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну, что-то такого вида:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    {
        ofstream out1("file1");
        for(int i = 0; i < 500; ++i) out1 << rand() << "\n";
        ofstream out2("file2");
        for(int i = 0; i < 500; ++i) out2 << rand() << "\n";
    }
    vector<int> s1, s2, s3;
    {
        int n;
        ifstream in1("file1");
        while(in1 >> n) s1.push_back(n);
        ifstream in2("file2");
        while(in2 >> n) s2.push_back(n);
    }
    sort(s1.begin(),s1.end());
    sort(s2.begin(),s2.end());
    set_difference(s1.begin(),s1.end(),s2.begin(),s2.end(),back_inserter(s3));
    {
        ofstream out("file3");
        for(int n: s3) out << n << "\n";
    }

}
```